# Read/write strings in Python using Zeroconf/PyBonjour

Tags: python, ios, zeroconf

I'm trying to implement simple string passing over Bonjour/Zeroconf, between a client iOS app and server Python process.

The server reads a string sent from the iOS app, and echoes back the same string. Very straightforward, Apple has code sample for how to this (i.e. CocoaEcho), and I've implemented the client side code in my iOS app. This works great, I can discover the server service, connect to it and pass strings which are echoed right back.

I am now trying to port or otherwise write the server that echoes the string, in Python using either the PyBonjour or Zeroconf module. Where I'm stuck is how best to handle I/O, and since I'm not familiar with streams in Python I'm wondering what's the best way to do this, and if any Python examples of exactly this exist already. Weirdly enough I've had no luck finding a Zeroconf-specific example so far; Has anyone done something similar, or know of sample code, or otherwise have a good roadmap of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For others coming here:
Zeroconf is about getting a client to find a service and which port to connect to.
Once that is done zeroconf is not part of the actual data communication between client and server.
There are tutorials on setting up a server in python for socket communication.
Here is one [Socket Programming in Python](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/).